# Any way to show that $x=2$ is only integer solution of this equation :$x^x-x^2(1-x)^4=0$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

$ x=2$ is clear that is a integer solution of this equation $x^x-x^2(1-x)^4=0$ , but to prove it it is hard by standard methods , I want if there is any method using variable change help me to solve this equation and to show that $x=2$ is only integer  solution of this equation :$x^x-x^2(1-x)^4=0$?
?

Comment: Probably you want to say that $2$ is the unique solution ?

Comment: it is the only integer solution this  what i meant

Comment: Hint: if$\,x\,$ is an integer then $\,\gcd(x, 1-x)=1\,$.

Comment: I don't want to solve it using number theory , i meant analytic method

Answer (score 3):

For $x\ge6$, $$x^x\ge x^6>x^2(1-x)^4$$ and there cannot be a solution.

You conclude by checking with the values $0$ to $5$. (And obviously negative integers can't do.)

Comment: The possibility of $x$ being 3 or 5 can be ignored

Comment: @FreeRadical: yes but this requires to develop some reasoning (admittedly pretty light), which takes about the same effort as brute force. Actually you discover that the odd values can't work while attempting the computation.

Comment: @FreeRadical: I don't think you understood my argument. My goal is to avoid reasoning. Here brute force is very cheap and safe.

Comment: I read that a bit too fast. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $x >2$ then your equation is 
$$x^{x-2}=(1-x)^4$$
and the two sides are relatively prime integers.

If $x <2$ your equation becomes
$$1=x^{2-x}(1-x)^4$$
and the RHS is the product of two integers.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is equivalent to
$$x^x=x^2(1-x)^4. $$
If, $x\geq2$ then
$$ x^{x-2}=(1-x)^4$$
and both sides are integers. We know $x=2$ is a solution to the equation, and if $x>2$, then $x$ divides the LHS of the equation, and therefore must divide the RHS, but $\gcd(x,1-x)=1$, which it can't happen. We know $x=1$ and $x=0$ is not a solution, and if $x<0$ the LHS of the first equation is not an integer, but the RHS is, hence they cannot be equal.

Answer (score 0):

$x^x-x²(1-x)^4=0$

So, $x^2 = \frac{x^x}{(1-x)^4}$

Since $x^2$ and $(1-x)^4$ are perfect squares, $x^x$ must also be a perfect square.

$x$ can't be 0

$x$ can only take values from 1 to 5 out of which $x^x$ is a perfect square only for 1, 2 and 4.

After substituting we can notice that only $2$ works.

Hence, $x$ = 2